# Why does the client gets the message only after closing the stream in this TLS connection?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to build a simple TLS connection on a local network. The client gets the message I'm trying to send only after closing the output stream (out). Closing the output stream closes the socket too. Another problem is that the client isn't getting the message correctly encoded (he gets something like &��!y�S}y.?'zn:�܋�zC£Cw8�J��=�������R��y)

I need to use the input and output streams to send messages back and forth.

I have used the `KnockKnockProtocol` class from [Oracle's website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockProtocol.java)

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    TlsServerProtocol tlserver = new TlsServerProtocol(clientSocket.getInputStream(),
            clientSocket.getOutputStream(), new SecureRandom());


    tlserver.accept(new MyTlsServer(certificateData));

    try (

        // to send to client
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(tlserver.getOutputStream(), true);
        // to receive from client
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tlserver.getInputStream()));
        ) {


        String inputLine, outputLine;

        KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
        outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("point 2");
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
            out.println(outputLine);
            if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                break;
        }


    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(
                "Exception caught when trying to listen on port " + PORT_NUMBER + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Client code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    TlsClientProtocol protocol = new TlsClientProtocol(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream(),new SecureRandom());

    // client
    DefaultTlsClient client = new DefaultTlsClient() {
        // getAuthentication should be implemented
        public TlsAuthentication getAuthentication() throws IOException {

            TlsAuthentication auth = new TlsAuthentication() {
                // Capture the server certificate information!

                // Called by the protocol handler to report the server certificate Note: this method is responsible for certificate verification and validation
                public void notifyServerCertificate(org.bouncycastle.crypto.tls.Certificate serverCertificate) throws IOException {
                }

                // Return client credentials in response to server's certificate request
                public TlsCredentials getClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest) throws IOException {


                    return null;
                }
            };
            return auth;
        }
    };
    protocol.connect(client);


    try (
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;
            String fromUser;

            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                    break;

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }

}
```

Comment: "The client gets the message I'm trying to send only after closing the output stream" - What happens if you don't close the output stream?

Comment: nothing happens if i don't close the stream.

Comment: The client code you have just edited in proves my point.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the client gets the message only after closing the stream in this tls connection?

Because the client must be in a read loop that only terminates at end of stream, which only happens when the peer closes the connection. It would have helped if you had posted the client code, but this much is inescapable.

> The problem is that Closing the output stream closes the socket too.

That's not a 'problem'. That's the [way it works - Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream--).

> Another problem is that the client isn't getting the message correctly (a problem with the encoding)

**What** 'problem with the encoding'? If you have such a problem, *post it.*  But the only thing that can happen with the code you posted is a `SocketException: socket closed` in the `readLine()` method.

> I need to use the input and output streams to send messages back and forth.

So don't close them, and don't read until end of stream if you're not going to get it.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. How can I keep the client in  a read loop ?  when the clients gets the message he gets something like this "Server: &��!y�S}y.?'zn:�܋�zC£Cw8�J��=�������R��y
"

Comment: how can I keep the server and the client in a read and answer loop until one of them decides to disconnect with some keyword ("Bye" for example) ? how can i let recognise the end of a stream?

Comment: You are already recognizing end of stream via `in.readLine()) != null)`. Unclear what you're now asking.